# How to do math with a number represented as an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have some `unsigned char` array. I want to represent a big number and add a number to this big number.

So for example I have these six elements:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xdf
```

I want to add `0x11` and get

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0
```

So, if I add `0x10` after, I should have

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00
```

Could I do it with binary operations or something another but without loops? My array could be much larger than six elements.

Comment: Show us what you have tried... Is this homework ?

Comment: look at any implementation of `BigInteger` (name taken from Java): there are many google-able answers to your problem.

Comment: if your array has 100 elements then, given how carry works, adding 1 to it could effect anywhere from just 1 to all 100 array elements - so either a loop or recursion is needed, and recursion seems like a poor fit. A simple while loop which implements what you learned about addition in elementary school seems like the natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

You sum each pair of bytes from the source arrays and if the result is larger then 0xFF you carry 1 to the next byte. A loop is required.

```
//Adds B to A, Len is the amount of bytes that will be added.
//Make sure that Len <= size of A
void Add(unsigned char *A, unsigned char *B, int Len)
{
    int Carry = 0;

    //Work backwards because the high byte of your array holds the least significant byte.
    for (int i = Len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int Temp = (int) A[i] + B[i];   
        A[i] = (Temp + Carry) & 0xFF;
        if ((Temp + Carry) > 0xFF)
            Carry = 1;
        else
            Carry = 0;
    }
}
```